# ComposeView steals focus from content in AndroidTV

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-tv, android-jetpack-compose-tv

I'm trying to use Jetpack Compose in my existing AndroidTV App.
I need to make a button with microphone icon which will change its color if it's focused. Like this^

Unfocused

[image]

Focused

[image]

Here's my ComposeView

```
<androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
    android:id="@+id/micBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

And here the code in my fragment

```
binding.micBtn.setContent {
    var buttonResId by remember { mutableStateOf(R.drawable.speech_recognition_button_unfocused) }
    IconButton(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(60.dp)
            .onFocusChanged {
                buttonResId = if (it.isFocused) {
                    R.drawable.speech_recognition_button_focused
                } else {
                    R.drawable.speech_recognition_button_unfocused
                }
            },
        onClick = onClick,
    ) {
        Icon(
            painter = painterResource(id = buttonResId),
            contentDescription = null,
            tint = Color.Unspecified,
        )
    }
}
```

Looks good, right?
The problem is when I try to focus on this button focus first goes to `AndroidComposeView` item (according to my `GlobalFocusListener`).
And only my second action (click, D-Pad navigation) makes my content focused.

So, for some reason internal `AndroidComposeView` steals focus from my `Content`

Is there any way to prevent this behaviour? I need to focus only on my content, not `AndroidComposeView` wrapper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Update (March 6, 2024):

This issue has been addressed in [aosp/2813125](https://android-review.googlesource.com/2813125) and the following hack shouldn't be required anymore. Just update to the latest version of Compose UI (1.7.x).

---

### First draft

This is a known issue where moving focus from outside of a ComposeView to inside the ComposeView needs 2 inputs from the user instead of just 1: [b/292432034](https://issuetracker.google.com/292432034)

You can create an extension function which can transfer the focus to the child using just 1 input from the user.

```kotlin
fun ComposeView.setFocusableContent(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    isFocusable = true
    isFocusableInTouchMode = true
    val focusRequester = FocusRequester()

    onFocusChangeListener = View.OnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
        if (hasFocus) focusRequester.requestFocus()
    }

    setContent {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.focusRequester(focusRequester).focusGroup()) {
            content.invoke()
        }
    }
}
```

Usage is pretty straight forward. Instead of using `setContent`, you can now use `setFocusableContent`.

```kotlin
binding.micBtn.setFocusableContent {
  // ...
}
```

---

### Unrelated to the question

To react to focus changes in your component, you can make use of [IconButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/tv/material3/package-summary#IconButton(kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.tv.material3.ButtonScale,androidx.tv.material3.ButtonGlow,androidx.tv.material3.ButtonShape,androidx.tv.material3.ButtonColors,androidx.tv.material3.ButtonBorder,androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource,kotlin.Function1)) from `androidx.tv.material3` library. By default, it changes color when the button is focused and it is easy to change the colors for different states (focused, pressed, etc.) using the `colors` parameter.

Usage:

```kotlin
androidx.tv.material3.IconButton(onClick = { }) {
    Icon(
        Icons.Filled.Mic, 
        contentDescription = "Mic"
    )
}
```